# How to use MD5OfMessageAttributes to verify a message has been received by AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

From AWS online document, [image]

- You can use this attribute to verify that Amazon SQS received the message correctly.

I am a bit confused about this statement,

- Does it mean I can conclude that a message has been successfully sent to an AWS server if a MD5OfMessageAttributes string is returned by an AWS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the md5 for the message at client side I.e. before putting your message in the queue. Set the calculated md5 value in the attribute. While putting the message into queue, the sdk will calculate the md5 and compare it with the given value. If both matches, then the message is not tampered in the network data transfer, so it will considered as good message and message put operation is successful.

If there is a difference, the put operation will be rejected.

If the md5 is not set at client side, sdk will not compare and reject the message though it still calculates the md5 for the received message.

The best practice is to set the md5 at client side and use this feature to avoid any message tampering issues.

Comment: when you say "message put", you meant "message sent." I am sorry that I have to be sure.

Comment: Yes, message sent.